# Are all the youtube videos encoded to pal or ntsc?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm handling time format conversion operations and i need to turn Secs into Timecode format: Hours:Minutes:Seconds:Frames.

To calculate the frames I need to know the video standard (PAL or NTSC), hence my question:

Are all the youtube videos encoded to pal or ntsc? or they keep the original uploaded video standard? And, if they keep the original standard, how can I retrieve this data?

Comment: I have looked at a few videos, and found frame rates from 14 to 60 fps. I suspect that the uploaders source is what dictates the frame rate. YouTube just recodes to bit rates for view ability.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of that whether it's PAL or NTSC in the docs.

However, I found this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube/KsNFSEvGSm8/nk0gPvcQSV8J) that says

> YouTube will accept both NTSC and PAL format, and on the internet, it
>   makes no difference at all. Use whichever format your original
>   material is in.

Youtube [video metadata](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) are returned after successful method calls to the Youtube API.